# Are we doing error codes wrong?

Tags: debugging, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error

I have great luck using a combination of Google (and usually StackOverflow) to locate help with errors in software. But I'm wondering if there's a better way. How about tagging all errors with a unique ID?

This is just a suggestion, hopefully someone will take this in an even better direction. As a starting point I see errors registered the way we register web sites. Maybe they are web sites. Each error would have a URL. And that URL would have an associated abbreviated version for cases where we want to reference the error but want to save space.

The app developer would be under no obligation to provide anything at the error URL location. That would be optional but nice. Maybe the URLs would all be based on a global domain like wikipedia where anyone can contribute info. My main goal though is just to tag errors with something to make web searched more effective when I'm looking for help.

Comment: Looks like a great suggestion! I am not sure if the place is right (may be it suits better for Meta or something), but I find the idea pretty much bright. If the project is started and you are aware of it, please contact me using the e-mail from my SO account.